# Is there a way to check if message.content on Discord contains a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

On my Discord server, I have a #selfies channel where people share photos and chat about them. Every now and then, I would like to somehow prune all messages that do not contain files/images. I have tried checking the documentation, but I could see not see any way of doing this. Is it not possible?

Comment: I think you should look at either [`discord.Message.attachments`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.attachments) or [`discord.Message.embeds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.embeds)

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate through every `message` and do:

`if not message.attachments:
    ...`

`message.attachments` returns a list and you can check if it is empty using `if not`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with `discord.py` (since I use `discord.js`), but if this is similar to `discord.js` there should be a `message event`. This event will run on every message, which is ideal for what you are searching for now. Now for the **pseudocode...**

```
//written in javascript
Message event:
On each message {
    if(message.attachments.size <= 0) {
        message.delete(); 
    }
}
```

The general idea is that using the `message event`, (so on each `message`), you check if the `message`'s attachments list is greater than 0 (meaning it **contains a file or image**) and if it is not, call the `delete()` function in python to delete the `message`.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @ADug's answer, `message.attachments` is a list of `discord.File`s in a message. But, `discordpy` has methods to help you purge messages!

You can use `channel.purge` on the #selfies channel.

```
def has_no_messages(message):
    return len(message.attachments) == 0
await channel.purge(limit=100, check=has_no_messages) # Specify an appropriate limit
```

You can also do this in a single line with lambda expressions:

```
await channel.purge(limit=100, check=lambda x: len(x.attachments) == 0)
```