# On message attachment delete, send an embed in the logs channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to code my bot into sending deleted messages & images/attachments into my logs channel. How may I fix my code?

```
#msg deleted

@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if message.attachments == None:
        embed = discord.Embed(description=f"**Message sent by <@{message.author.id}> deleted in <#{message.channel.id}>**\n {message.content}", timestamp = datetime.utcnow(), color = 0xff2222)
        embed.set_author(name=f"{message.author}", icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Author: {message.author.id} | Message ID: {message.id}")
        channel = bot.get_channel(channel id)
        await channel.send(embed=embed)

    if message.attachments == True:
        file = message.attachments
        embed = discord.Embed(description=f"**Image sent by <@{message.author.id}> deleted in <#{message.channel.id}>**", timestamp = datetime.utcnow(), color = 0xff2222)
        embed.set_author(name=f"{message.author}", icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Author: {message.author.id} | Message ID: {message.id}")
        embed.set_image(url=f'{file}')
        channel = bot.get_channel(channel id)
        await channel.send(embed=embed)

    else:
        return
```

Comment: `message.attachments` never returns a boolean, so the second if statement will never work, my question is -- why are you even using a second if-statement? Why not do it in the else part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`message.attachments`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message) returns a `list` of attachments, not a boolean (`True`/`False`). This can be seen in the image below:

[image: Image of sending result directly]

Instead, you will want to check if this list is empty, or if it has items in it. Do view the partially revised code below, along with further commented explanations. I have not included the code involving your embeds, as I'm sure you can do that on your own, and I would rather get straight to the point here.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if not message.attachments: # if the list has nothing in it
        # send embed without image

    if message.attachments: # if the list is not empty
        # send the image + embed
        if len(message.attachments) == 1: # If there is only one file...
            # retrieve the URL of the image
            file = message.attachments[0].url

        else: # if there's more than one file
            # you will want to send multiple embeds/images
            # I will not show this here
```

**Other Links:**

- [Check if message has attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64021606/check-if-message-has-an-attachment-in-discord-py) - Stackoverflow
- [Check if message.content on Discord contains a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255732/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-message-content-on-discord-contains-a-file) - Stackoverflow
- [Get a picture from the message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206958/get-a-picture-from-the-message) - Stackoverflow
- [Python Lists](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) - w3schools